# How to display a ground truth image segmentation mask image in python?

Tags: python, image-segmentation

I tried this piece of code

```py
from skimage import io
temp = io.imread(mask_input_path)
plt.imshow(temp)
```

This displays it a normal image, hence the output is black.

[image: Image plot]

Answer (score 1):

Just like a normal image. If your entire mask is black that means desired object is not present in your image.

But to select only masked area you need 2 extra lines on code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
input_img = plt.imread('img.jpg')
mask_img  = plt.imread('mask.jpg')

# select only masked area below
masked = input_img.copy()
masked[mask_img == 0 ] = 0

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(16, 12))
ax = axes.flatten()

ax[0].imshow(input_img, cmap="gray")
ax[0].set_axis_off()
ax[0].set_title("Original Imput Image", fontsize=12)

ax[1].imshow(mask_img, cmap="gray")
ax[1].set_axis_off()
ax[1].set_title("Mask", fontsize=12)

ax[2].imshow(masked, cmap="gray")
ax[2].set_axis_off()
ax[2].set_title("Masked", fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Actually using

```
masked[mask_img < 30 ] = 0
```

gives slightly better results because mask values are not exactly zero in my case

[image]

Comment: This works in the case of binary masks because 0 is taken as black and 1 as white. What about the case of multiclass segmentation.
Here the image is a 2D array with each element an integer corresponding to the class. 
Eg: Each pixel belongs to 0 to 7 corresponding to the 7 classes.